# How do I compute $v$ from angular speed cross radius when using Lorentz force equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors

I'm working on a problem in Griffiths E&M and I can't seem to figure out to get
$$\vec{v}=R\omega\hat{\phi}+\dot{z}\hat{z}$$ from just $R$ which is the radius of a disk centered at the origin in the $xy$-plane. It revolves around the $z$-axis with $\omega_0$.

If $\vec{\omega}=\omega_0\hat{\phi}$ and $\vec{r}=R\hat{s}$, then $\vec{v}=\vec{r}\times\vec{\omega} = \omega R\hat{z}$.

I don't think that I have the correct expression for $\vec{\omega}$ because $\vec{\omega}=\dot{\phi}\hat{z}$ ...

The actual problem:
A circular disk of radius $R$ and mass $M$ carries $n$ point charges $q$, attached at
regular intervals around its rim. At time $t = 0$ the disk lies in the $xy$ plane, with its center at the origin, and is rotating about the $z$ axis with angular velocity $\omega_0$, when it is released. The disk is immersed in a (time-independent) external magnetic field
$$\vec B(s, z) = k( -s \hat{s} + 2z\hat{z}),$$
where $k$ is a constant.

In cylindrical coordinates $(\hat{s},\hat{\phi},\hat{z})$, where $\hat{s}$ points radially away from the $z$-axis and $\hat{\phi}$ is the angle in the $xy$-plane measured from $x$-axis and $\hat{z}$ is the distance along the central axis.

Comment: $\vec{\omega}=\omega_0\hat{\phi}$ doesn’t describe rotation around the $z$-axis.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have figured it out. The disk has some initial angular speed given by $\omega_0$ but the angular velocity of the cylindrical basis is given by $\vec{\omega}=\dot{\phi}\hat{z}$. That would give me $$\vec{\omega} = \omega_0 \hat{\phi} + \dot{\phi}\hat{z} \;.$$
The cross product is then
$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{s} & \hat{\phi} & \hat{z}\\ 
0 & \omega_0 & \dot{\phi}\\ 
R & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$$
This results in $\vec{v} = R\dot{\phi}\hat{\phi} -R\omega_0 \hat{z} = R\omega \hat{\phi} - v_z\hat{z}$.